# Strings between 2 characters unix

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cut

First I would like to apologies for posting similar thread which is present. But since I was not able to solve it hence I am posting it.

I have a wired string pattern ( mongo output) which I need to convert to only values.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("59280d9b95385c78b73252e4"), "categorySetId" : NumberLong(1100000041), "categorySetName" : "PROD GROUP", "serviceableProductFlag" : "N", "categoryId" : NumberLong(1053), "pid" : "800-319-03", "productFamily" : "PP", "productType" : "SEATS", "subGroup" : "PP SER", "description" : "^AY,EECH, NG-C", "inventoryItemId" : NumberLong(200699), "itemStatusMfg" : "S-INTV", "organizationIdMfg" : NumberLong(90000), "src" : "orcl", "syncedOn" : NumberLong("1495797136138"), "CreationDate" : ISODate("2017-05-26T11:12:16.138Z"), "CreatedBy" : "tool", "LastUpdatedDate" : ISODate("2017-05-26T11:12:16.138Z"), "LastUpdatedBy" : "tool", "itemFamilyDesc" : "PP FAMILY", "itemFamilyGroupId" : 750, "itemFamilyGroupName" : "PP SERIES PRODUCTS"
```

I want output like

```
59280d9b95385c78b73252e4,1100000041,PROD GROUP,N,1053,800-319-03,PP, SEATS,PP SER ,'^AY,EECH, NG-C', 200699,S-INTV,90000,orcl,1495797136138,2017-05-26T11:12:16.138Z,tool,2017-05-26T11:12:16.138Z,tool,PP FAMILY,750,PP SERIES PRODUCTS
```

I have tried various sed and awk but I am not able to achieve it .

```
sed 's/"[^"]*://g' text.txt
sed 's/"[^:]*://g' text.txt
```

Can someone help me with it ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of such a long line, break it down... use a minimal example, say 3-5 elements... and is the input some kind of xml, json, etc? is so there are better tools than using regex

Comment: Use a programming language that provides a mongo client library

Comment: So you want the single input value `"^AY,EECH, NG-C"` (from `"description" : "^AY,EECH, NG-C"`) to become 3 separate output values `^AY,EECH,NG-C`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F': +|, *"' '{ r=""; for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) { 
         gsub(/^ *([^(]+\()?|"|\)$/,"",$i); 
         if(index($i,",")!=0){ $i="\047"$i"\047" } r=(r!="")? r","$i : $i 
     } print r }' text.txt
```

The output:

```
59280d9b95385c78b73252e4,1100000041,PROD GROUP,N,1053,800-319-03,PP,SEATS,PP SER,'^AY,EECH, NG-C',200699,S-INTV,90000,orcl,1495797136138,2017-05-26 11:12:16.138Z,tool,2017-05-26 11:12:16.138Z,tool,PP FAMILY,750,PP SERIES PRODUCTS
```

---

- `-F':|, *"'` - field separator
- `for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)` - iterating through all *even* fields
- `gsub(/^ *([^(]+\()?|"|\)$/,"",$i)` - replace/remove excessive instance names like `ObjectId(` and double quotes `"`

Comment: Yes. That is a single field

Comment: @user2854333, if this value `"^AY,EECH, NG-C"` should not be separated, it should remain as is (enclosed with double quotes)

Comment: @user2854333 What does "Yes. That is a single field" mean? Clearly it's one field in your posted sample input but it's just as clearly 3 fields in your posted expected output so - is your posted expected output wrong? If so, obviously, fix it to be whatever it's supposed to be.

Comment: @EdMorton, I've added some workaround, you can check (at least, we have the expected output)

Comment: @user2854333, you may apply my solution if it solves your issue

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest There are only 2 issues left .. 1st "description" : "^AY,EECH, NG-C", is coming as diff field . Can we get it like '^AY,EECH, NG-C' . Other issue is with date  "LastUpdatedDate" : ISODate("2017-05-26T11:12:16.138Z") is coming as seperate field 2017-05-26T11 and 16.138Z

Comment: @user2854333, you need to post the exact final output in your question so I can see it

Comment: Just added space to sep the output :-- 59280d9b95385c78b73252e4 , 1100000041 , PROD GROUP , N , 1053 , 800-319-03 , PP, SEATS , PP SER ,'^AY,EECH, NG-C', 200699 , S-INTV , 90000 , orcl , 1495797136138 , 2017-05-26T11:12:16.138Z , tool , 2017-05-26T11:12:16.138Z , tool , PP FAMILY , 750 , PP SERIES PRODUCTS

Comment: @user2854333, I've asked *to post the exact final output in your **question***, as it should be there, not in comments

Comment: Current Output :-- 59280d9b95385c78b73252e4,1100000041,PROD GROUP,N,1053,800-319-03,PP,SEATS,PP SER,^AY,EECH, NG-C,200699,S-INTV,90000,orcl,1495797136138,2017-05-26T11,16.138Z,tool,2017-05-26T11,16.138Z,tool,PP FAMILY,750,PP SERIES PRODUCTS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146278/discussion-between-user2854333-and-romanperekhrest).

Comment: @user2854333, do you understand the phrase *post the exact final output in your question* ?

Comment: Thank you . Really appreciate your efforts

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest .. I did one small mistake in my expected result and that was with date . I have corrected the same. the date should have been 2017-05-26T11:12:16.138Z.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your field values have embedded commas, so this is most likely an exercise in futility, but...

```
#! /bin/sed -rf

s/\s*"[^"]+"\s*:\s*\w+\s*\("([^"]*)"\)\s*/\1/g
s/\s*"[^"]+"\s*:\s*\w+\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*/\1/g
s/\s*"[^"]+"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"\s*/\1/g
s/\s*"[^"]+"\s*:\s*([0-9]+)\s*/\1/g
```